# How to save the friend ID in Facebook TD Friend Selector

Tags: php, facebook, selector, friend

I used this Facebook Friend Selector script from GitHub:

> http://playground.thesedays.com/tdfriendselector/

and it works perfectly fine. But I don't know how to save the selected output friend in PHP as the README file documentation is very poor. If anyone could assist, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Save it where? In a database?

Comment: @KyleBoddy, i just want to ouput it on PHP. Example: `<?php echo "Selected friend id is: $id"; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

When you create the instance add the callbackSumbit Option and the function you want to use for it.

For example:

```
//the function we want to use as event listener on submission
alertFriends = function(selectedFriendIds) {
    //whatever you want to do with the array of FB Friend Ids
    alert('I got them');
}

mySelector  = TDFriendSelector.newInstance({callbackSubmit  : alertFriends});
```